# Read arbitrary amount of memory with process_vm_readv

Tags: c, linux

For process_vm_readv the linux man page states:

> [...] (Avoid) spanning memory pages (typically 4KiB) in a single remote iovec element. (Instead, split the remote read into two remote_iov elements and have them merge back into a single write local_iov entry. The first read entry goes up to the page boundary, while the second starts on the next page boundary.)

Now I'm a bit confused by this. I get why this is a thing but I don't quite understand how I should work around it. Do I somehow need to find out where the page boundaries are? Or does the function figure this out on it's own as long as I provide 2 remote_iov elements? And if I read more than 4kiB and potentially cross 2 page boundaries. Do I need to split the remote element into 3 parts?